# Win32 MessageBox doesn't appear

Tags: messagebox, winapi

I'm stuck with a strange problem. I'm making a Win32 application in VC++ 2008, making a class to encapsulate most of the work for easy repetition when calling a `MessageBox`. The message box` is created (I think) but doesn't show up unless I press the Alt key!

What happen exactly is :

1. I run the program
2. press Enter
3. the main window lose focus
4. give beep sound when i click on the main window as if a modal MessageBox is present
5. either press Escape... focus is gained OR press Alt then the MessageBox appear with alt key pressed (i.e. menu will drop )!!!!!!

P.S. It was working fine but suddenly this happened. I didn't find any difference - I even made a new project!

This is supposed the Main program:

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR    lpCmdLine, int       nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;
    CWnd    cMainWindow(TEXT("DentoMan"), TEXT("Bejkoman")); // pass The class name and window name to the constructor

    cMainWindow.CreateDef(); //Create the Window
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

While This is the Class file

```
CWnd::CWnd() {
};

CWnd::CWnd(LPTSTR lpszClassName, LPTSTR lpszWindowName) {
    CWnd::lpszClassName     = lpszClassName;
    CWnd::lpszWindowName    = lpszWindowName;
};

CWnd::~CWnd() {
};

// Create the window with default parameters
HWND CWnd::CreateDef(void) {
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = StaticWndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wcex.hIcon          = 0;
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 4);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = 0;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = lpszClassName;
    wcex.hIconSm        = 0;

    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
    g_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0,lpszClassName, lpszWindowName, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, wcex.hInstance, this);
    hInst   =   wcex.hInstance;  //Store hInstance in the class hInst variable

    if (!g_hWnd) return false;
    ShowWindow(g_hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(g_hWnd);

    return g_hWnd;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK CWnd::StaticWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    /* The Only Message we take here so we store the 'this' pointer within the window to identify messages 
    comming from it by the 'this' pointer*/
    if ( Message == WM_CREATE ) {
        SetWindowLong( hWnd, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG)((CREATESTRUCT FAR *)lParam)->lpCreateParams);
    }

    /* Store the window pointer in the class pointer we just created in order to run the right public WndPRoc */
    CWnd *Destination = (CWnd*)GetWindowLong( hWnd, GWL_USERDATA );

    // If the hWnd has a related class, pass it through
    if (Destination) {
        return Destination->WndProc( hWnd, Message, wParam, lParam );
    }

    // No destination found, defer to system...
    return DefWindowProc( hWnd, Message, wParam, lParam );
};

LRESULT CWnd::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    // Determine message type
    switch (Message) {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            {
                /* this is a common trick for easy dragging of the window.this message fools windows telling that the user is
                 actually dragging the application caption bar.*/
                 SendMessage(hWnd, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION,NULL);
                break;
            }

        /*case WM_CREATE:
            break;
    */

        case WM_CLOSE:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            UnregisterClass(lpszClassName, hInst);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        case WM_KEYDOWN:    //KeyBoard keys
            // Which key was pressed?
            switch (wParam) {
                case VK_ESCAPE: //close through escape key
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                    return 0;
                case VK_RETURN:
                    MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("DFGDGD"), TEXT("DFGDFG"), NULL);
                    return 0;
            } // End Switch

            break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            /*switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        }*/
        break;

        case WM_PAINT:
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Message, wParam, lParam);

    } // End Message Switch

return 0;
};
```

The Class Header:

```
class CWnd {
    public:
        CWnd();
        CWnd(LPTSTR lpszClassName, LPTSTR lpszWindowName);
        virtual ~CWnd();
        virtual HWND CreateDef(void);           // Create the window with default parameters
        virtual LRESULT     WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );

    private:
        static LRESULT CALLBACK StaticWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
        HWND        g_hWnd;     //Global window handle for this window
        HINSTANCE   hInst;      //Global instance for this window

        LPTSTR          lpszClassName;
        LPTSTR          lpszWindowName;
};
```

P.S. I included all needed header files, everything goes fine except MessageBox

This is also a link to the code on [here](http://ideone.com/ONBbD)

Comment: Post the relevant code here. Also, a shot in the dark: specify a parent window when showing the message box.

Comment: Edited, linked removed. Don't post unsafe .exe files.. Just paste the relevant code.

Comment: ... or you can put the code to [ideone](http://ideone.com/) or [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: @Jim Brissom, you may as well pass NULL as the window's handle in this function and it should work (at least it does in my case). Not sure if it's correct (maybe I should use `HWND_DESKTOP` or something instead), but it works anyway.

Comment: if u use null or whatever handle the same problem happen,

Comment: HWND_DESKTOP is actually defined as 0. What I was referring to is the fact that unless you specify a parent window, the message box may be hidden under a topmost or modal window.

Comment: May ancient posts never die... FWIW, I was having this problem, where ::MessageBox() didn't appear (in a win 64 MFC app that called ::MessageBox()). I could fix it by passing AfxGetMainWnd()->m_hWnd for the hWnd (rather than nullptr) **or** by passing MB_DEFAULT_DESKTOP_ONLY as the flag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ohhhhhhh finally i found the solution of this problem ... and for everyone to benefit the problem was in WndProc(.......) at the WM_PAINT  Message i wrote some code in it and removed all the code along with BeginPaint and EndPaint functions so the program enter a freeze period once anything is being painted over it including that MessageBox but it only show when i press Alt i think coz the control is transfered to the system in that step to show the system Menu (i think)

the solution either remove the WM_PAINT message handler or add the normal BeginPaint and EndPaint functions

Thanks for everyone who passed on my question

Answer (score 8):

If anyone is still interested, this method works:

```
MessageBox(NULL,L"error",L"Error",MB_ICONERROR|MB_DEFAULT_DESKTOP_ONLY);
```

Comment: I had this problem, and adding the `MB_DEFAULT_DESKTOP_ONLY` flag did solve. So did adding `MB_TASKMODAL`. Do you have an explanation for why either of these flags fixes this problem?

Comment: (sorry, no, I was confused, `MB_TASKMODAL` did not solve the problem, only `MB_DEFAULT_DESKTOP_ONLY` did. I'm very curious to what's going on here)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem that was cause by WM_PAINT as somebody above mentioned. Solved it by adding `return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Message, wParam, lParam);` there.

Answer (score 2):

When you create your MessageBox you should pass `WS_CHILD` in CreateWindowEx.
**EDIT 2:**
Ok try this.

```
MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("DFGDGD"), TEXT("DFGDFG"), MB_OK);
```

Comment: I can't do it Ramilol this is my main window, i'm calling MessageBox function through it ...

Comment: sorry didn't notice that...  I can't really understand what your saying..  Your message box doesn't show up or your main window?

Comment: What happen exactly is :

1 - I run the program

2 - press Enter

3 - the main window lose focus

4 - give beep sound when i click on the main window as if a modal MessageBox is present

5 - either press Escape... focus is gained OR press Alt then the MessageBox appear with alt key pressed (i.e. menu will drop )!!!!!!

Comment: Same problem may be it's a problem with my system am working on windows 7 x64 while compiling the program as 32 bit!!

Comment: @Ramilol Ohh i've just got to the solution and added the answer thanks for ur effort ... if u have any comment plz tell me

Answer (score 0):

Try using MB_TOPMOST:
`MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("DFGDGD"), TEXT("DFGDFG"), MB_TOPMOST);`