# MessageBox not being displayed

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

When trying to display a simple MessageBox it does not display at all.

Code:

```
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{
    try
    {
        Window wnd( { 50, 50 }, Graphics::ScreenWidth, Graphics::ScreenHeight, "Bat Engine", Graphics::FullScreen );
        throw std::exception( "test" );
    }
    catch( const std::exception& e )
    {
        MessageBox( NULL, e.what(), "Error", MB_ICONWARNING | MB_OK );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The return value for `MessageBox` is `IDOK` which is supposed to mean I clicked the OK button even though that's not the case. GetLastError also doesn't return any errors.

Furthermore, this only happens if I throw the exception after I initialize my Window. The Window class can be found here: https://github.com/SlidyBat/BatEngine/blob/2a1427265d359949a6f3f5a160d553990656354e/Engine/Window.cpp

After looking around for this issue online I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41171505/9094644

Sure enough if I clear the message queue before displaying the message box ([like this](https://github.com/SlidyBat/BatEngine/commit/465e78389ffedbc8e209b62ac14449d1f704ef7e)) it works. The messages that are in the queue when clearing it are WM_QUIT, WM_TIMER and a message with ID 1847 (not sure what that one is).

For now I'm just clearing the message queue before displaying the message box to ensure it works, but it would be nice to find out what exactly I'm doing wrong to cause this.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like something called `PostQuitMessage()`.  Put a breakpoint on that and then look at the stack trace to see what's calling it.

Comment: look like `WM_QUIT` in your message queue. if you call `MessageBox` at this time - it just exit. if you remove this `WM_QUIT`  - `MessageBox` run as usual

Comment: Well, there's no need to trace code, as simply looking into `Window` class source code reveals that it always posts quit message when destroyed. So such behaviour is "not a bug but feature" ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I set a breakpoint and found that it was being called by DestroyWindow in ~Window (or rather that lead to PostQuitMessage being called in my message handler). After commenting out that line the message box displays as expected. <3

Comment: @Slidy `DestroyWindow()` does not post a `WM_QUIT` message. Neither does `WM_DESTROY` when passed to `DefWindowProc()`. This is because an app can have multiple windows active at a time. Destroying *any* window should not terminate the app. Only when destroying the "main" window, for instance. So, somewhere in code you have not shown, `PostQuitMessage()` must be getting called.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this now. I was misinterpreting what `PostQuitMessage` was for, I was under the impression it was a message to terminate the window rather than terminate the app. I just removed the `PostQuitMessage` in my message handler entirely and used a kill flag to end processing messages instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `WM_QUIT` message is telling your application to quit. To prevent any modals from eating the message or being processed properly Windows automatically prevents a number of windows from finishing creation if there is a WM_QUIT message in the queue.

[The Old New Thing on WM_QUIT and modality](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050222-00/?p=36393)

If this is not the behaviour you want, then you need to change your `Window` class implementation to not `PostQuitMessage` when it errors / exits.

---

*All credit to @Remy Lebeau for finding the link.*

Comment: Related: [Modality, part 3: The WM_QUIT message](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050222-00/?p=36393)

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to include that but had lost it.

Comment: Link has changed: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050222-00/?p=36393