# WIN32:C++, why is calling the Messagebox function on WM_CLOSE The program is freezing

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I'm learning about creating a Windows desktop application using Visual C++.
I am creating a simple window that does nothing, and when I press the close button, I wanted to display a message box to confirm that I really want to close it before I close the window.
So I tried to do this using the Messagebox function when I got the WM_CLOSE message, but for some reason the program froze and wouldn't close.
I'm sorry, but can someone help me out?
The source is as follows. Thank you for your help.

```
#include<Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
ATOM InitApp(HINSTANCE);
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);

TCHAR szClassName[] = TEXT("winapp");       

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hCurInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpsCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {                                                       
    MSG msg;
    BOOL bRet;
    if(!InitApp(hCurInst))
        return FALSE;
    if (!InitInstance(hCurInst, nCmdShow))
        return FALSE;
    while ((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0) {
        if (bRet == -1) {
            MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("GetMessageエラー"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
            break;
        }
        else {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessageW(&msg);
        }
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

ATOM InitApp(HINSTANCE hInst) {
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;     
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;   
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;      
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;                  
    wc.hInstance = hInst;               
    wc.hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(                
        NULL,                                   
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION),   
        IMAGE_ICON,                             
        0,                                          
        0,                                  
        LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_SHARED);            
    wc.hCursor = (HCURSOR)LoadImage(        
        NULL,           
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ARROW),                 
        IMAGE_CURSOR, 
        0, 
        0,
        LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_SHARED);        
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH); 
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;                     
    wc.lpszClassName = szClassName;             
    wc.hIconSm = (HICON)LoadImage(                  
        NULL,
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION), 
        IMAGE_ICON,
        0, 
        0, 
        LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_SHARED);

    return (RegisterClassEx(&wc));
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInst, int nCmdShow) {
    HWND hWnd;                          
    hWnd = CreateWindow(
        szClassName,                    
        TEXT("Winapp"),                     
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            
        CW_USEDEFAULT,                  
        CW_USEDEFAULT,  
        CW_USEDEFAULT,      
        CW_USEDEFAULT,      
        NULL,                   
        NULL,                       
        hInst,          
        NULL);
    if (!hWnd)
        return FALSE;
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
    int id;

    switch (msg){
    case WM_CLOSE:
        id = MessageBox(hWnd,TEXT("終了してもよろしいですか？"),TEXT("終了確認"),MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION);
        if(id==IDYES){
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return (DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wp, lp));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code works without freezing for me. In your test. when the program freeze? always after clicking ok?

Comment: I tried your code and it worked ok. What stage did it freeze at?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but you can call `DefWindowProc` (rather than `DestroyWindow`) from your `WM_CLOSE` handler if the user clicks Yes.

Comment: @Ali Askari, Jonathan Potter
-Thanks for your comments. The window is generated fine, but when I press the close button, The message box was not generated, the window froze and the task manager was launched and Otherwise, will not be able to exit. To try and remove the statement for the Messagebox function in WM_CLOSE And it works fine and can exit with the close button.
I thought there might be a problem with the use of the Messagebox and the way the WM_CLOSE message is handled, but no matter how much I look into it, there doesn't seem to be a problem with the code, so I'm having trouble...

Comment: @PaulSanders
Thanks for the interesting information. By the way, calling DefWindowProc instead of DestroyWindow If so, how will it behave? As a newbie, if it doesn't bother you, could you please let me know for later study...?

Comment: When you pass `WM_CLOSE` on to `DefWindowProc` it destroys the window for you.  This is the idiomatic way to do this.

Comment: @PaulSanders
Thanks for your reply, I'm not sure that DefWindowProc has that kind of use. I've never heard of it before! I'd like to try it out at hand, looking into the specifications of the function as well.

Comment: Could you debug to see if the MessageBox statement is executed? Confirm whether the MessageBox statement is not executed or executed without normal display, and you can try to call MessageBox elsewhere to confirm whether the function can be used normally.Thanks.

Comment: @tayu It is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close)

Comment: @Zhu Song
Thanks for your comment. When I ran it in other blocks, WM_CREATE, etc., it worked perfectly fine. Also, in WM_CLOSE, I used TextOut to see how far it was working correctly. When I checked, Messagebox worked fine at that time. However, when I removed all of the debugging code, it still didn't seem to work.

Comment: @PaulSanders
Thank you! I will use this as a reference.

Comment: Try calling `MessageBox` with a `NULL` parent.  Passing the window which is closing as the parent sounds a bit iffy to me.

Comment: @tayu You could try pressing the Alt key to see if this dialog box appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try explicit use of unicode in your program. for exsmple using MessageBoxW instead of MessageBox and L"終了してもよろしいですか？" instead of TEXT("終了してもよろしいですか？") and change your windowproc a bit:

```
#include<Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
ATOM InitApp(HINSTANCE);
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);

TCHAR szClassName[] = TEXT("winapp");       

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hCurInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpsCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {                                                       
    MSG msg;
    BOOL bRet;
    if(!InitApp(hCurInst))
        return FALSE;
    if (!InitInstance(hCurInst, nCmdShow))
        return FALSE;
    while ((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0) {
        if (bRet == -1) {
            MessageBoxW(NULL, L"GetMessageエラー", L"Error", MB_OK);
            break;
        }
        else {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessageW(&msg);
        }
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

ATOM InitApp(HINSTANCE hInst) {
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;     
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;   
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;      
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;                  
    wc.hInstance = hInst;               
    wc.hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(                
        NULL,                                   
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION),   
        IMAGE_ICON,                             
        0,                                          
        0,                                  
        LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_SHARED);            
    wc.hCursor = (HCURSOR)LoadImage(        
        NULL,           
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ARROW),                 
        IMAGE_CURSOR, 
        0, 
        0,
        LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_SHARED);        
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH); 
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;                     
    wc.lpszClassName = szClassName;             
    wc.hIconSm = (HICON)LoadImage(                  
        NULL,
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION), 
        IMAGE_ICON,
        0, 
        0, 
        LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_SHARED);

    return (RegisterClassEx(&wc));
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInst, int nCmdShow) {
    HWND hWnd;                          
    hWnd = CreateWindow(
        szClassName,                    
        TEXT("Winapp"),                     
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            
        CW_USEDEFAULT,                  
        CW_USEDEFAULT,  
        CW_USEDEFAULT,      
        CW_USEDEFAULT,      
        NULL,                   
        NULL,                       
        hInst,          
        NULL);
    if (!hWnd)
        return FALSE;
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
    int id;

    switch (msg){
    case WM_CLOSE:
        id = MessageBoxW(hWnd,L"終了してもよろしいですか？", L"終了確認",MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION);
        if(id==IDYES){
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        }
        return 0;
        

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        
    }
    return (DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wp, lp));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
 For starters, there was no change in the way you answered...
I've tried many other things.
If you run Messagebox with other blocks or other messages such as WM_CREATE, it can be used in It worked fine. Also, in WM_CLOSE, there is a statement to get the device context handle and When I added TextOut, Messagebox worked. The only thing that doesn't seem to work is the first code.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to press the close button, but the MessageBox does not pop up. Try to press the ALT key to see if it pops up. I suggest you handle the WM_PAINT message to ensure that the drawing message is processed.

Code:

```
#include<Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
ATOM InitApp(HINSTANCE);
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);

TCHAR szClassName[] = TEXT("winapp");

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hCurInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpsCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    MSG msg;
    BOOL bRet;
    if (!InitApp(hCurInst))
        return FALSE;
    if (!InitInstance(hCurInst, nCmdShow))
        return FALSE;
    while ((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0) {
        if (bRet == -1) {
            MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("GetMessageエラー"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
            break;
        }
        else {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessageW(&msg);
        }
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

ATOM InitApp(HINSTANCE hInst) {
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(
        NULL,
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION),
        IMAGE_ICON,
        0,
        0,
        LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_SHARED);
    wc.hCursor = (HCURSOR)LoadImage(
        NULL,
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ARROW),
        IMAGE_CURSOR,
        0,
        0,
        LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_SHARED);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = (HICON)LoadImage(
        NULL,
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION),
        IMAGE_ICON,
        0,
        0,
        LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_SHARED);

    return (RegisterClassEx(&wc));
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInst, int nCmdShow) {
    HWND hWnd;
    hWnd = CreateWindow(
        szClassName,
        TEXT("Winapp"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInst,
        NULL);
    if (!hWnd)
        return FALSE;
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
    int id;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_PAINT:
        BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        id = MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("終了してもよろしいですか？"), TEXT("終了確認"), MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION);
        if (id == IDYES) {
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return (DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wp, lp));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

More reference:[Why would a message box be not displaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41106365/why-would-a-message-box-be-not-displaying)